# Efficient way to filter a json array of json objects in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json sample like this:

```
{"ratings": [{

    "TERM": "movie1",       
    "Rating": "3.5",
    "source": "15786"

},
{
    "TERM": "movie2",       
    "Rating": "3.5",
    "source": "15786"
},
{
    "TERM": "Movie1",       
    "Rating": "3.0",
    "source": "15781"
}

]}
```

Now I want to create a new json file out of this and logic to filter is to ignore a json object if TERM is already present once. So, for this sample the output will be

```
{"ratings": [{

"TERM": "movie1",       
"Rating": "3.5",
"source": "15786"

},
{
"TERM": "movie2",       
"Rating": "3.5",
"source": "15786"
}
]}
```

As movie1 is is already present in index 0 we want to ignore index 2.

I came up with this below logic which works fine for small samples. I have a sample with json array size of 10 milliion and this below code takes 2+days to complete. I am wondering if there is much more efficient way to do this:

```
import json
import io
input1 = "movies.json"
res=[]
resTerms = []
with io.open(input1, encoding="utf8") as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(len(d['ratings']))
    for x in d['ratings']:
        if x['TERM'].lower() not in resTerms:
            res.append(x)
            resTerms.append(x['TERM'].lower())


final ={}
final["ratings"] = res
output =  "myFileSelected.json"
with io.open(output, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(final, outfile)
```

Comment: The most time you spend on **read\write** operation. Try to use [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of `io` library, it works faster.

Comment: You could split each item down into a dictionary of `{x['TERM'].lower(): []}` and then write out only the first entry of each key rather than checking each TERM against an array of entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is when you check if the term is already present (i.e. when you check `if x['TERM'].lower() not in resTerms:`). This is because `resTerms` is a `list` and the lookup complexity is O(n) therefore the whole algorithm becomes O(n^2)

The way to solve this is to use a `set` instead of a `list` which has lookup coplexity if O(1). Then your loop would look something like this (you also do not need to keep the json file open)

```
import json
import io
input1 = "movies.json"
res=[]
resTerms = set()
with io.open(input1, encoding="utf8") as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(len(d['ratings']))

for x in d['ratings']:
    if x['TERM'].lower() not in resTerms:
        res.append(x)
        resTerms.add(x['TERM'].lower())
```

A handy guide of Python data structures and time complexities can be found here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity